# Selenium jars are imported and after test execution getting ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:3427)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:2019)
at org.testng.internal.XmlMethodSelector.checkMethod(XmlMethodSelector.java:238)
at org.testng.internal.XmlMethodSelector.setXmlClasses(XmlMethodSelector.java:257)
at org.testng.TestRunner.initRunInfo(TestRunner.java:410)
at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:292)
at org.testng.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:223)
at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
at org.testng.ITestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(ITestRunnerFactory.java:55)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:659)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:173)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.(SuiteRunner.java:107)
at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1300)
at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1276)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1125)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
... 24 more

Answer (score 0):

Java ClassNotFoundException occurs when the application tries to load a class but Classloader is not able to find it in the classpath.

Please refer to the below link:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-classnotfoundexception-java-lang-classnotfoundexception